# When my viewDidDisappear I try to release my table. Still there when I get back to the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I declare my table like so:

```
    CGRect cgRct = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 363);
videoTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct style:UITableViewStylePlain];
videoTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoTable.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
videoTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
videoTable.dataSource = self;
videoTable.delegate = self;
videoTable.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
videoTable.bounces = NO;
videoTable.allowsSelection = YES;
//self.videoTable.layer.zPosition = -1;
//table.dragging = NO;
[self.view addSubview:videoTable];
```

I remove my table when we leave the view

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
NSLog(@"*viewDidDisappear");
if (videoTable)
{
    NSLog(@"removing table");
    [videoTable removeFromSuperview];
    videoTable.delegate = nil;
    [videoTable release];
   // self.videoTable = nil;
}
}
```

When the view loads again there is no sign of the table, but.. it is still there because

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self populateFileList];

if (videoTable)
{
    NSLog(@"table still here");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"No table");
}
}
```

Can anybody explain what it is that I am missing? I want the table completely gone, so I can alloc a new table.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign nil to the table after you release it, otherwise, the variable still have a value (an old reference to the table object):

```
[videoTable release];
videoTable = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self setVideoTable:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (videoTable) is true if videoTable is different from nil. So you need to assign your table to nil after releasing it.